# COUNTIF and auto filter disagree about trailing spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel, whitespace

I have an Excel spreadsheet. In column A I have these values at the top:

```
Title
A
A␣
B
B
```

where I have used `␣` to indicate a space. Just a normal space, like you get from the spacebar.

Now, to my mind this makes the values in cells A2 and A3 *different*, and `COUNTIF` agrees with me:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "A")
```

returns 1, as does

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "A ")
```

By contrast

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "B")
```

returns 2, since there are two cells that are (just) `B`.

However, if I use Filter (on the Data tab of the ribbon), it decides that there are only two distinct values in my Title column:

[image: The 'filter on Title' dropdown, with checked checkboxes for Select All, A, and B]

and if I uncheck everything except `A`, I get

[image: Column A filtered to only show data rows for A2 and A3]

Even if I do a custom filter for equality

[image: A custom AutoFilter for equality with "A"]

it still gives me two rows. Even if I ask for equality with `"A "`!

**How do I get the Filter to acknowledge that `"A"` does not equal `"A "` ?**

Comment: I don't think you can in the autofilter.  But you can with the Advanced Filter using a Formula as the criteria.

Comment: Yes is true that Auto filter can't be used as in usual way but helper data can support Auto filter as show by #Lee. As well Advance filter can be applied using criteria `"A " `. It's a good issue so I vote for U and Lee too ☺

Answer (score 2):

In Text Filter cannot return the text end with a space or enter.

You can use this formula to check if the text end with space or enter:

```
=or(code(right(A1))=10,code(right(A1))=32)
```

Comment: Good one @Lee ,,, +10 ☺